# Why do I need to register $moment with the $injector before each Jasmine test?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

So, I'm writing some Jasmine unit tests for a controller which utilizes Moment.js. Moment.js is included in app.js like so:

```
.config(function ($momentProvider) {
  $momentProvider
    .asyncLoading(false)
    .scriptUrl('bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js');
})
```

Then, I can just inject $moment into wherever. $moment isn't directly called from the controller, but some of the directives on the controlled page use it.

Originally, the controller unit tests failed with errors like these:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cProvider <- c <- $moment <- myService <- $moment
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cProvider <- c <- $moment <- $moment
```

Later, I added some code to register $moment with the $injector inside of beforeEach, as follows:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module('myApp');
  module('socketMock');

  module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$moment', moment);
  });
});
```

I don't understand why this is necessary. I use other services in the controller (i.e. $cookieStore, $stateParams, and a whole bunch of custom services) that don't require this. Could it because those services are injected directly into the controller, but $moment is not ($moment is injected into some directives on the page, but not the controller)?

Comment: Does the module that your controller belongs to depend on the moment module?

Comment: @dskh I do not include the moment module as a dependency via angular.module('myApp', ['$moment']), if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The module that your directive/controller under test is in needs to depend on the moment module.  It probably won't be called $moment - the $moment *service* is part of the moment *module*.

Let's take the example of one of your working services: $stateParams.  You are not needing to stub $stateParams because your module will depend on ui.router i.e.

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ui.router'])
```

The *$stateParams* service is part of the *ui.router* module, so by depending on the ui.router module we can inject $stateParams.

I can't tell you the exact name of the module that $moment is in from the code provided, but hopefully the example above can help